# Cannot see the Publish options in Wordpress 4.6.1

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

After installing Wordpress 4.6.1 I cannot post to the blog even being the Admin.
So I tried creating different user types but the Publish option still remains hidden.

I have no plugins running and the blog is on the twentysixteen theme.

Attached Image for reference.

Anything else is missing from the setup? This user is the admin user.

[image]

If I try to edit my own Draft it takes me to the "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit posts in this post type." page
[image]

And if I click on Posts it takes me to "Invalid post type."
[image]

Does this have anything to do with my nginx config?

```
location /blog {

        alias /usr/share/nginx/blog/wordpress;
        rewrite ^blog/([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~* \.php {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/blog\/)(.+\.php)(.*);
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

Update: 1

I was on php5.5, the wordpress blog says minimum version should be 5.6 so now I've updated to php7 no sucess.

Update 2

Downgraded to Wordpress 4.5.3, using php7 and nginx still same issue

Comment: Seems like this has happened to at least one other person.. Misery loves company, right? Do the symptoms listed in this thread also apply to your install? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/another-invalid-post-type-problem-and-more/

Comment: I did a fresh install, didn't upgrade from any previous table. I guess I'll reinstall WordPress and check.

Comment: Similar problem happened to me a couple of times (with earlier versions), and the problem was always with FTP - I uploaded a directory, but not all the files were uploaded by FTP in that directory. I had to copy the files a couple of times to check to be sure, that all of them "have arrived" on the server.

Comment: i did a wget inside the ssh terminal so no ftp was used in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After purging php5, installing php7, reinstalling php7, downgrading to a lower version, re updating to 4.6.1 it's finally done.

I had to do comment the fastcgi_split_path_info for it to work.

```
location /blog {

        alias /usr/share/nginx/blog/wordpress;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite /blog/wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
            rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
            rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;
        }   

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/blog\/)(.+\.php)(.*); #worked after commenting this!
            #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something may've gone wrong during the upgrade process. Do you happen to have a backup of your site?

I found this thread that deals with similar issues:
https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/custompress-invalid-post-type-errors

One quick fix suggested would be to try rebuilding the indexes in the wp_ database tables. https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/496

Other than that, it looks like this user solved the problem by dumping all of his content via the XML export tool in WordPress, and starting essentially from scratch with a re-import of that data. Not sure if that's an option for you.

Comment: Well this is a fresh install. I didn't upgrade from an earlier version.